# How to install nodemon Nodejs on macOS? nodemon keeping show : command not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, npm, nodemon

Currently I already install nodemon with command `npm install -g nodemon`. And I got Permissions issue, so I do command with `sudo npm install -g nodemon` and i did it. But when I make "nodeman" command was always show `nodemon: command not found`.

Comment: Try `export PATH=$PATH:~/npm`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If for any reasons you are unable to set a Global PATH then under your current project directory, run

```
npm install nodemon --save-dev
```

then under "scripts" in your package.json file, add "start": "nodemon app.js" like this -

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
}
```

then run

```
npm start
```

Comment: Thank u it's work for me. But I still wonder, why i've to add this "start": "nodemon app.js" on my package.json?

Comment: With that written, you'll be able to run "npm run start" and then the mapped script ( which is "nodemon app.js" will run).

Comment: Note: npm adds ./node_modules/bin to the working path, so that scripts will be able to use executable scripts installed to the local node modules...  I actually have that added to my path statement as-is, so that I can use local node module bin scripts without issue.

Answer (score 14):

If you need to install nodemon globally on mac OS, try

`sudo npm install -g nodemon`.

Then you'll have to enter your password. Once the installation is completed successfully, run

`nodemon -v`

to check nodemon version on terminal.

Answer (score 6):

According to [this](https://www.kevinhooke.com/2018/02/09/fixing-npm-global-install-permissions-on-macos/), Create a new directory to store your `global` packages. So that there is no permission issue.

```
mkdir ~/.npm-global
npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
```

Edit your **.profile** or **.bash_profile** to add the new location to your PATH:

```
export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
```

Then install the package without `sudo`:

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

Comment: Thanks - this worked a treat and feels organised in handling global packages :praying-hands:

Answer (score 2):

If you want to install global nodemon use SUDO, because if you need to be a global user, you need to be a super user

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is correct but my advice is that it's better to not install packages globally if you can help it, this makes your application self sufficient without relying on the environment and avoids versioning issues between applications.

```
npm install -D nodemon
```

You can now execute nodemon from `scripts` in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "nodemon src/index.js"
}
```

Or you can execute it yourself using `npx` if you're in that directory from the terminal. npx executes local scripts, e.g. `npx nodemon --inspect ./src/index.js 8080`

Answer (score 0):

Just run these commands and the error will get solved.
Specially for MAC People:

1. `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}`
2. Enter your laptop password
3. `npm install i -g nodemon or npm install -g nodemon`

All set .....